# Express routes DRY code

Tags: express

I'm creating several routes with the same functionality. Is there a better DRY method to creating these routes instead of copying and pasting them like I have below?

```
app.get('/adminoverviews', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.status(403);
      res.redirect('/login');
      res.end();
    }else{
      next();
    } 
},function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs',{
          bootstrappedUser: req.user,
          page: 'admin'

        })
    }); 
app.get('/adminoverviews/:id', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.status(403);
      res.redirect('/login');
      res.end();
    }else{
      next();
    } 
},function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs',{
          bootstrappedUser: req.user,
          page: 'admin'

        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first seperate `authenticate` into it's own declaration

```
var authenticate = function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.status(403);
      res.redirect('/login');
      res.end();
    } else {
      next();
    }
}
```

If your route function is different for `/adminoverviews` vs. `/adminoverviews/:id`:

```
app.get('/adminoverviews', authenticate, function(req, res) {

}

app.get('/adminoverviews/:id', authenticate, function(req, res) {

}
```

Otherwise you may to do something similar to what was done with `authenticate`

You may need to do some validation with `:id`. I'd suggest using `router.param`.
http://expressjs.com/api#router.param